# Sorting Tablesorter columns by input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery Tabelsorter and it's working great.

But I want inside every -field an input-tag where the value for the sorting-script is located inside the input value param.

**NOW:** `<td><?php echo $value; ?></td>`

**GOAL:** `<td><input value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></td>`

How can I tell jQuery Tablesorter the new "value" location?

Found at Tablesorter 2.0 Samples http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html

Example:

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
            // extract data from markup and return it  
            return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; 
}
```

My try but not working:

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
            // extract data from markup and return it  
            return node.childNodes[0].val();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of table sorter use kendoui.its provide more features & easy to use 
[kendoui](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)

Comment: That's a nice alternative, but why suggest something that costs a lot of money when there are free products out there just as good?

Answer (score 0):

Tthe original tablesorter plugin has an issue using the `updateCell` method, so this method will not work when updating input values. But you can try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which doesn't have this issue.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1247/) of the all of the code below put together.

Basically instead of using `textExtraction` which applies to ALL table cells, you just need to add a parser:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "inputs",
    is: function () {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        return $(cell).find('input').val() || s;
    },
    type: "text"
});
```

then tell tablesorter which column to apply it to (zero-based index):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: "inputs" } // zero-based index (first column = column 0)
    }
});
```

Then make sure any changes to the inputs (unless you make them read-only) are recognized by tablesorter and sent to your server

```
var resort = true, // resort table after update

// update all input types within the tablesorter cache when the change event fires.
// This method only works with jQuery 1.7+
// you can change it to use delegate (v1.4.3+) or live (v1.3+) as desired
// if this code interferes somehow, target the specific table $('#mytable'),
// instead of $('table')
$(window).load(function () {
    // this flag prevents the updateCell event from being spammed
    // it happens when you modify input text and hit enter
    var alreadyUpdating = false;
    $('table').find('tbody').on('change', 'input', function (e) {
        if (!alreadyUpdating) {
            var $tar = $(e.target),
                $table = $tar.closest('table');
            alreadyUpdating = true;
            $table.trigger('updateCell', [ $tar.closest('td'), resort ]);

            // *** update your server here ***

            setTimeout(function () {
                alreadyUpdating = false;
            }, 10);
        }
    });
});
```